# Elasticearch Watcher error for range

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

```
PUT _xpack/watcher/watch/log_error_watch
   {
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "10s"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "indices": [
          "filebeat-2017.01.02"
        ],
        "body": {
          "sort": [
            {
              "@timestamp": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          ],

          "query": {
            "range": {
              "offset": {
                "gte": 1000,
                "lte": 2000
              }
            }, 

            "match": {
              "source": "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
            }
          },
          "size": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [hj-test156] [gc][11042] overhead, spent [701ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-01-02T15:32:04,311][ERROR][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hj-test156] failed to execute [search] input for watch [log_error_watch], reason [[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is malformed, you need to write it like this

```
...
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "offset": {
              "gte": 1000,
              "lte": 2000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "source": "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
...
```

**UPDATE**

For a `range` with a date field you can do it like this:

```
 {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gte": "2017-01-02T05:23:34.731Z",
          "lte": "2017-01-03T05:23:34.731Z"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: thank you. How do i do same thing with date. How do i take range for dates with format "@timestamp": "2017-01-02T05:23:34.731Z"